# reject возвращает пустой массив

Tags: javascript, promise

Хочу сделать чтоб программа при  варианте ID которого нет в объекте, возвращала текст 'Пользователь не найден'(reject). Но в итоге получается пустой массив. 
 Подскажите где совершил ошибку ?

```js
const USERS = [
  { id: '001', name: "Алексей", age: 25 },
  { id: '002', name: "Иван", age: 28 },
  { id: '003', name: "Егор", age: 30 },
];

function fetchUser(id) {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
    const objId = USERS.filter( u => u.id == id)
    
      if (objId) {
      resolve(objId)
      }else {
      reject(new Error('Пользователь не найден'))
      }
    }, 2500)
  });
}

async function start() {
  try {
    const result = await fetchUser('004');
    console.log(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  } 
}

start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) всегда возвращает массив.

Проверка пустого массива в `if` всегда `true` - поэтому до `reject` даже не доходит.

Так как должен найтись только один объект, вместо `.filter` стоило использовать [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
const USERS = [{
    id: '001',
    name: "Алексей",
    age: 25
  },
  {
    id: '002',
    name: "Иван",
    age: 28
  },
  {
    id: '003',
    name: "Егор",
    age: 30
  },
];

function fetchUser(id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const objId = USERS.find(u => u.id == id)

      if (objId) {
        resolve(objId)
      } else {
        reject(new Error('Пользователь не найден'))
      }
    }, 2500)
  });
}

async function start() {
  try {
    const result = await fetchUser('004');
    console.log(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}

start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Должно быть так:

```
if (objId.length > 0 ) {
```

т.к. `objId` это массив. И даже пустой он не даёт ни коим образом `false`

Comment: Вы правы, метод filter  тут не подходит, с find все работает как и задумывал. Спасибо за помощь!